# Run Mink with Selenium2 from php

Tags: php, symfony, selenium, testing, mink

In my symfony2 project I want to be able to run specific scenarious from my service using Mink tests with Selenium2 without writing behat scenarious.

Some abstract Example how i imagine this:

```
class MyService extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * @var Mink $mink Mink
     */
    private $mink;

    /**
     * Set up
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->mink = new Mink();
        $this->mink->setUp($this->createSeleniumDriver());
    }

    /**
     * Run scenario
     */
    public function runScenario()
    {
        $this->visit('http://google.com.com');
        $this->pressButton('Google Search');
    }
}
```

So i want to be able to connect Mink with Selenium driver and then all my Mink tests run in some browser like in does Behat when you specify **@javascript** tag for behat scenario.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

So I check Mink's documentation and found [this](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium2.html). You should create Selenium2Driver using specific browser as class parameter:

```
$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver('firefox');
```

After that you need create a Mink session using this driver:

```
$this->session = new Session($driver);
$this->session->start();
```

And and you can run Mink scenarious from this session:

```
$this->session->visit('http://stfalcon.com');
$this->session->getPage()->clickLink('EN');
```

If you want to create custom scenario like in Behat FeatureContext you can do this like that:

```
/**
 * Clink on element with css
 *
 * @param string $element Element pattern
 *
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 */
public function iClickOn($element)
{
    $element = $this->fixStepArgument($element);

    $selectedElement = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $element);

    if (!$selectedElement) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot find element with selector: "%s"', $element));
    }

    $selectedElement->click();
}

/**
 * Returns fixed step argument (with \\" replaced back to ").
 *
 * @param string $argument
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function fixStepArgument($argument)
{
    return str_replace('\\"', '"', $argument);
}

/**
 * Get session
 *
 * @return Session Session
 */
public function getSession()
{
    return $this->session;
}
```

Good luck!